# creating a Base64 string with encoding get bytes in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, encode

I have really struggled to find the javascript equivalents to this C# code.

```
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        return "Basic " + authInfo;
```

Can any one help with this basic base64 encoding?

Comment: [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) encodes and [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) decodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: So you know this part: Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo) is that all within btoa()

Comment: It would just be `authInfo = btoa(authInfo)`

Comment: ahh right, okay thank you, needed to know for sure because connecting to this API is not the easiest.